# Passing parameters from angular http.get to c# controller

Tags: c#, angular, http

I want to pass parameters to a get function.

I'm writting a Rent project where the user has to choose car maker, from date, till date etc. and by these parametes I need to search the DB. The HPPT.GET method returns an error

```
//My Class
export class SelectParams {
    Gear: number;
    MakeYear: number;
    Maker: number;
    Degem: number;
    StartDate: string;
    EndDate: string;
    FreeText: string;
}

//My Http.get
Sparams: SearchParams = new SearchParams();
 let httpParams = new HttpParams().set('Id',this.Sparams.toString());    
    let options = { params: httpParams }; 
this.h.get(this.CarUrl,options).subscribe(
      code => {
        this.CarDbData = code;
        this.CarVec = this.CarDbData as Car[];
        console.log("this is select component");
        console.log(this.CarVec);
      });

//This is my c#
public class SelectParams
    {
        public int Gear;
        public int MakeYear;
        public int Maker;
        public int Degem;
        public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public string FreeText;
    }
 public IEnumerable<Car> Get(SelectParams SParams)
        {
            Car CarV = new Car();
            return CarV.SelectByParams(SParams);
        }
```

I get http 400 bad request.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not a C# expert but in Angular you are passing a parameter called `Id` but i don't see this name in your c# file

Comment: You are right @LucaRegazzi, please pass corresponding parameter(name and value)

Comment: Thanks for seeing this. Fixed it once with -->set('Sparams',this.Sparams.toString()); <-- and once with -->set('SelectParams',this.Sparams.toString());<-- In both times I got 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a few thigs to solve this and I don't realy know what helped.
I added [DataContract] and [DataMember] to my class - this did not help at this stage.
I created a new controller and tried to activate it. Now I got to the controller post function. Parameters were returned but parameters did not go in.
Since how I get to the server is not realy important I changed to HTTP.PUT.
I still had an issue with that. I saw an error message about multiple instances and the IIS not knowing which one to activate so I erased the default put function that came with the controller and now everything works fine. All I need to do now is to enhance my select statement from the DB.